# función ventana para calcular existencia por estado ignorando los duplicados

Tags: sql, postgresql, agrupación

Tengo un tabla en dónde me mandan la información sobre unos pedidos, artículo, cantidad pedida, bodega , estado, etc. En rojo marco los datos que necesito calcular.

[image: Tabla de pedidos]

A partir de esta información necesito hacer unos calculos para mostrar lo disponible por bodega y por estado, pensé que era muy simple con un par de funciones ventana:

```
SELECT *,
EXISTENCIA_BOD - SUM(CANT_PEDIDO) over(partition by ARTICULO, BODEGA) as DISPONIBLE_BODEGA,
SUM(EXISTENCIA_BOD) over(partition by ARTICULO, ESTADO) as EXISTENCIA_ESTADO,
EXISTENCIA_BOD - SUM(CANT_PEDIDO) over(partition by ARTICULO, ESTADO) as DISPONIBLE_ESTADO
FROM PEDIDO
ORDER BY ESTADO DESC
```

La primera función calcula sin problemas lo disponible por bodega, pero para los calculos de estado se complica ya que cada linea me indica la existencia de la bodega y hay pedidos hacia la misma bodega, ¿conocen que filtro me podría ayudar a eliminar este problema? Cualquier tip es bien recibo, la consulta anterior, suma la información duplicada que tengo en la existencia por bodega.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para replicar el ejemplo en postgres:

```
create table pedido
(
 id_pedido bigint not null primary key,
 articulo character varying(20),
 bodega character varying(20),
 estado character varying(10),
 no_pedido integer,
 existencia_bod integer,
 cant_pedido integer
 
);

insert into pedido 
values
(1,'ITEM1','COA','VER',343,10,2),
(2,'ITEM1','COA','VER',302,10,1),
(3,'ITEM1','XAL','VER',567,15,1),
(4,'ITEM1','PUE','PUEB',567,5,1);
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que `existencia_bod` debería a estar en otro lado, ya que es un dato que pertence a la relación entre el articulo y la bodega, no?

Comment: si es correcto, existe como tal una tabla de existencia para la bodega de la cual está obteniedo la existencia mostrada en la linea, creé la tabla virtual (o como se le llame) e hice el join basandome en solución que propones con lo que el problema fue resuelto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema básicamente esta en obtener el valor correcto de `EXISTENCIA_ESTADO` que sería el resultado de sumar `existencia_bod` agrupando primero por `articulo, estado, bodega` y después por `articulo y estado`.

La consulta para esto podría ser la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT 
  T.articulo,
  T.estado,
  SUM(T.total_bodega) AS total_bodega
FROM (
  SELECT 
    articulo,
    bodega,
    estado,
    MAX(existencia_bod) total_bodega
  FROM pedido
  GROUP BY articulo, bodega, estado
) AS T
  GROUP BY articulo, estado
```

La cual devuelve:

| articulo | estado | total_bodega |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | VER | 25 |
| ITEM1 | PUEB | 5 |

---

Si tomamos la consulta anterior, la agregamos a la consulta principal usando CTE y hacemos un `JOIN` podemos realizar los calculos muy facilmente.

```sql
WITH articulo_bodega_estado AS (
  SELECT 
  T.articulo,
  T.estado,
  SUM(T.total_bodega) AS total_bodega
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      articulo,
      bodega,
      estado,
      MAX(existencia_bod) total_bodega
    FROM pedido
    GROUP BY articulo, bodega, estado
  ) AS T
  GROUP BY articulo, estado
)
SELECT 
    P.*,
    P.existencia_bod - SUM(P.cant_pedido) OVER (PARTITION BY P.articulo, P.bodega) as DISPONIBLE_BODEGA,
    ABE.total_bodega AS EXISTENCIA_ESTADO,
    ABE.total_bodega - SUM(P.cant_pedido) OVER (PARTITION BY P.articulo, P.estado) as DISPONIBLE_ESTADO
FROM pedido AS P
    LEFT JOIN articulo_bodega_estado AS ABE
        ON P.articulo = ABE.articulo
        AND P.estado = ABE.estado
ORDER BY estado DESC
```

Obteniendo así el siguiente resultado:

| id_pedido | articulo | bodega | estado | no_pedido | existencia_bod | cant_pedido | disponible_bodega | existencia_estado | disponible_estado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ITEM1 | COA | VER | 343 | 10 | 2 | 7 | 25 | 21 |
| 2 | ITEM1 | COA | VER | 302 | 10 | 1 | 7 | 25 | 21 |
| 3 | ITEM1 | XAL | VER | 567 | 15 | 1 | 14 | 25 | 21 |
| 4 | ITEM1 | PUE | PUEB | 567 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 4 |

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTkuChCi3dHryizhZTf22/0)